# Font-Family using default font

Tags: html, css, fonts

I want to use the Lato LIGHT font and downloaded it into my fonts folder: fonts/Lato-Light.ttf

This is my CSS File:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'LatoLightFont';
    src: url(../fonts/Lato-Light.ttf) format('ttf')
}

body {
    font-family: 'LatoLightFont', "Courier New";
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 32px;
    font-weight: 200;
}
p {
    font-family: 'LatoLightFont', "Courier New";   
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: 'LatoLightFont', "Courier New";
}
```

But the font of my website is Courier New instead of Lato-Light. What is wrong?

The problem is that I want to use Lato, but the LIGHT version. I thought that I can use the LIGHT version by using font-style: Light, but this is also not working.

Comment: Are there any errors in your console that suggest the font can't be found or downloaded? It's worth noting that the documentation for the [`@font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) rule on MDN suggests that the format for `ttf` fonts should be `format(opentype)` rather than `format(ttf)`.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. opentype is the solution. Can you write an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be an error in the `format()` function/property, you have:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'LatoLightFont';
    src: url(../fonts/Lato-Light.ttf) format('ttf')
}
```

Whereas it should be, from reference to the documentation hosted at Mozilla:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'LatoLightFont';
    src: url(../fonts/Lato-Light.ttf) format('opentype')
}
```

References:

- [`@font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face).